# How to track mobile location using traccar open source?

Tags: ios, geolocation, tracking

I am trying to track my iPhone using traccar.
I installed traccar server in windows 7 and ios client application in iphone 4s.
I added my iPhone successfully in traccar web application and it is updating location per minute. 
But in traccar we application when I load my phone it always display error "No results found for selected period"

Below is a log file of traccar server...

> 2015-01-27 11:59:44
>   INFO: Starting server...
>  2015-01-27 11:59:44 INFO: Operating
>   System name: Windows 7 version: 6.1 architecture: x86 2015-01-27
>   11:59:44 INFO: Java Runtime name: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation version: 25.31-b07
>  2015-01-27 11:59:44 INFO:
>   Memory Limit heap: 247mb non-heap: 0mb
>  2015-01-27 11:59:44 INFO:
>   Version: 2.11-SNAPSHOT
>  2015-01-27 12:02:39 DEBUG: [5005 <-
>   192.168.1.59] - HEX: 24504749442c3838353839352a30300d0a
>  2015-01-27 12:02:39 WARN: Unknown device - 885895
>  2015-01-27 12:02:42 DEBUG:
>   [5005 <- 192.168.1.59] - HEX:
>   244750524d432c3036333231342e3030302c412c323833362e383730352c4e2c30373732312e373135302c452c302e30302c3131362e30322c3237303131352c2c2a30300d0a
>   2015-01-27 12:03:46 DEBUG: [5005 <- 192.168.1.59] - HEX:
>   244750524d432c3036333331352e3030302c412c323833362e383731362c4e2c30373732312e373134322c452c302e30302c302e30302c3237303131352c2c2a30300d0a

Please provide appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your device through web interface with 885895 as a unique identifier.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I was trying this application in my office. You know that GPS doesn't work indoors so you will have to go outside with your Iphone. Try it if work.

Best of luck!